# confusion over keeping js file from view in mvc asp.net

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, callback

i am new in MVC,i know i have to keep js separated from my view,but for some specific scenarios i do not know how should i keep this separation, for example,
i have a class of java script which creates chart for upon a call,in this scenario in my view i have a ajax call,i get the data and pass into the function like below:

```
pieChartForInterventions($("#pieChart"), result);
```

the function is in a seperated js file :

```
function pieChartForInterventions(chartID,pieChartData) {

      chartID.kendoChart({
      dataSource: {
      data: pieChartData
       },
     series: [{
    type: "pie",
    field: "list",
    categoryField: "mm",
    padding: 0,
    labels: {
        visible: true,
    }
   }],

    tooltip: {
    visible: true,
    template: "${ category }"  }
,
   legend: {
    position: "bottom"
  }
   });

   }
```

it works fine for me,the problem is there when i want to have a seriesClick event on this function,which returns me the series which i have clicked,i need this value to send it back to controller to get another data,if i write all this in the js file,then i cant have the value of seriesClick event in my view

seriesClick event works like this:

```
chartID.kendoChart({
dataSource: {
    data: pieChartData
},
series: [{
    type: "pie",
    field: "list",
    categoryField: "mm",
    padding: 0,
    labels: {
        visible: true,
    }
}],
seriesClick:onDb,
tooltip: {
    visible: true,
    template: "${ category }"
}
,
legend: {
    position: "bottom"
   }
});

function onDb(e) {    
  var _clicked = e.category;
         }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're not *required* to put your JS in a separate file from your view in any web application (not just ASP.NET MVC). It's certainly good practice in many ways (and necessary if you have a Partial View loaded via AJAX, because scripts in there will not be executed), but equally if you have something which is specific to that view only, IMO it's acceptable to put it into that view in a script tag.

However, is there any reason you can't supply a callback method to your JS file and use that as the seriesClick event for this occasion? Something like this:

JS file:

```
function pieChartForInterventions(chartID,pieChartData,seriesClickCallback) {
  chartID.kendoChart({
    dataSource: {
      data: pieChartData
    },
    series: [{
      type: "pie",
      field: "list",
      categoryField: "mm",
      padding: 0,
      labels: {
        visible: true,
      }
    }],
    tooltip: {
      visible: true,
      template: "${ category }"  
    },
    legend: {
      position: "bottom"
    },
    seriesClick: seriesClickCallback
  });
}
```

Main View:

```
//callback function
function onDb(e) {    
  var _clicked = e.category;
}

//create pie chart and pass in callback for seriesClick
pieChartForInterventions(someID,someData,onDb);
```

That way you can separate the chart functionality and make it re-usable in a separate file, but have the flexibility to be able to hook it back into your main view code when you need to respond to an event on the chart. That is one of the clever things about callbacks.

Comment: wwooow you saved me hours,thats working like a charm,and now i have a reusable js file,perfect,and now i think its way better than keeping my js in view,its less complicated and more readable

Comment: @mrslt No problem, it's a good trick to know. Lots of JS libraries you encounter will employ exactly the same technique. It's the same idea as when you attach a "click" event to a button and that kind of thing - you always supply a callback function which runs when the event occurs.